# how to copy a directory in ant

Tags: java, apache, ant

Say I have directory structure like this:

> base_dir1/src_dir
>
> base_dir2/dest_dir

How do I copy `src_dir`(folder + contents) into `dest_dir`.

If I use copy task like this:

```
<copy todir="base_dir2/dest_dir">
    <fileset dir="base_dir1/src_dir"/>
</copy>
```

It will copy all the contents of `src_dir` into `dest_dir`, but will not create a `src_dir` folder inside `dest_dir`.

I can make it work by using the copy task like this:

```
<copy todir="base_dir2/dest_dir">
    <fileset dir="base_dir1">
      <include name="src_dir/"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Is this the correct way or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: And it works for me. The Ant version: 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could do this.

```
<copy todir="base_dir2/dest_dir/src_dir">
    <fileset dir="base_dir1/src_dir"/>
</copy>
```

The folder (or part of the folder) specified by `todir` need not exist.

`<fileset>` refers to *contents* of the specified folder (excluding it).